# css not working locally or on remote website - but works on jsfiddle?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have a website which has a css menu on it. The dropdown items are being displayed but as soon as you try to click on the item the dropdown closes. The nav works on JSFiddle 
[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ccslabs/hfg29qj6/)

However it doesn't work either locally or when deployed.
[Deployed version](http://ccslabs-test.azurewebsites.net/)

The menu html looks like this: (partial page)

```
<div>
    <ul id="menu">

        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu dropdown"><a href="#" class="drop">Testing</a>  
        <div class="dropdown_1column">        
            <div class="col_1">                
                <ul class="simple">
                    <li><a href="/testing/">Overview</a></li>

                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Accreditation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>

        <li class="menu_right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>

        <li class="menu_right dropdown" ><a href="#" class="drop">About</a>  
            <div class="dropdown_1column align_right">        
                <div class="col_1">                
                    <ul class="simple">
                        <li><a href="#">Our Standards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Scientists</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Sponsosrs</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the css looks like this:

```
body, ul, li {
    font-size:14px; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:21px;
    text-align:left;
}

#menu {
    list-style:none;
  /*  width:940px; */
    margin:3px auto 0px auto;
    height:43px;
    padding:0px 2px 0px 20px;

    /* Rounded Corners */

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    /* Background color and gradients */

    background: #014464;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));

    /* Borders */

    border: 1px solid #002232;

    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    border:none;
}

#menu li.dropdown:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;

    /* Background color and gradients */

    background: #F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));

    /* Rounded corners */

    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#menu li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
}

#menu li:hover a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #000;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #AAF;
}

#menu li.dropdown:hover a {
    color:#161616;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
}
#menu li .drop {
    padding-right:21px;
    background:url("/img/drop.png") no-repeat right 8px;
}
#menu li:hover .drop {
    background:url("/img/drop.png") no-repeat right 7px;
}

.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
    margin:4px auto;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    border-top:none;

    /* Gradient background */
    background:#F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown_1column {width: 140px;}
.dropdown_2columns {width: 280px;}
.dropdown_3columns {width: 420px;}
.dropdown_4columns {width: 560px;}
.dropdown_5columns {width: 700px;}

#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
    left:-1px;
    top:auto;
}

.col_1,
.col_2,
.col_3,
.col_4,
.col_5 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.col_1 {width:130px;}
.col_2 {width:270px;}
.col_3 {width:410px;}
.col_4 {width:550px;}
.col_5 {width:690px;}

#menu .menu_right {
    float:right;
    margin-right:0px;
}
#menu li .align_right {
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
}

#menu li:hover .align_right {
    left:auto;
    right:-1px;
    top:auto;
}

#menu p, #menu h2, #menu h3, #menu ul li {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:21px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu h2 {
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    margin:7px 0 14px 0;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666666;
}
#menu h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:7px 0 14px 0;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
}
#menu p {
    line-height:18px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

#menu li:hover div a {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#015b86;
}
#menu li:hover div a:hover {
    color:#029feb;
}


.strong {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.italic {
    font-style:italic;
}

.imgshadow { /* Better style on light background */
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    margin-top:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
}
.img_left { /* Image sticks to the left */
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 15px 5px 5px;
}

#menu li .black_box {
    background-color:#333333;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    /* Shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
}

#menu li ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 12px 0;
}
#menu li ul li {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
    width:130px;
}
#menu li ul li:hover {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#menu li .greybox li {
    background:#F4F4F4;
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
    width:116px;

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu li .greybox li:hover {
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
    margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
}
```

The menu does not rely on JQuery or any other scripts.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to the least amount that still represents your problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do think that this is happening because your heading 'The Computer Crime Service Laboratories' is overlaying on the dropdown so you will be hovering over the heading not the dropdown that is why the dropdown disappears give the dropdown menu a higher z-index value if it is positioned it will help you

Comment: Hmm strange I thought that was set! Thanks for noticing that. For others z-index doesn't actually work unless you have position: set to something.

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: @DaveGordon i said give a z-index value if it is positioned

Comment: So you did !! Another thing I didn't notice, I will blame it on being 4.12am here :P

Comment: @DaveGordon it's 9.43 am here

Answer (score 4):

Going off of Akshay's suggestion, I added the following style to your site.

> .dropdown {    z-index: 100; }

It appears to have fixed the issue. As you can see, the dropdown menu is highlighted, persisting underneath my mouse pointer.

[image: z-index of 100 solves the problem]

Comment: Nice never even thought of doing something like that